# How to set the values of cascading lookup columns using javascript

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, lookup-column, cascading

I have two lookup fields that are cascaded with each other like:
1. Function and 2.category. First I select Function based on that Category field gets value.

But I have to set value in these two fields based on selection of other lookup ID field.

I am able to set value in Function field using below code. But is not getting set for category as I am not performing any action on Function field hence value is going to Category field. Can anyone help on this?

```
var checkfunction = ListItem.get_item("Functionn").get_lookupValue();
var allOptions = document.querySelectorAll("[title=Functionn] option");

[].some.call(allOptions, function(option) {
if (option.innerHTML == checkfunction ) {
    option.selected = "selected";
    return true;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by customizing the form in infopath for add list item.

Hope this helps.
Link:
https://myspexp.wordpress.com/2011/05/09/cascading-drop-downs-in-sharepoint-lists/

Comment: You can add some brief details from the link. This will preserve content here on this site. Links may get broken.